# React router V5 optional path

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How i can declare optional /submit path without copy/paste Route component ?

```
<Route path="/find/:id?/:lastName?" exact render={() => <FindOrder onSuccess={onOrderRecieved} />} />
<Route path="/find/:id?/:lastName?/submit" exact render={() => <FindOrder callSubmit={true} onSuccess={onOrderRecieved} />} />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string[]` syntax:

```
<Route path={[path1, path2]} render={...} />
```